# This rebus has a movie in it

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

Requires a bit of lateral thinking, but this rebus hides the name of a movie.

[image]

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: @Rubio Should I accept an answer if it reached the correct guess by a different logic than intended?

Comment: If the answer and the explanation haven’t completely missed the mark, accepting would probably make sense - perhaps with an edit to the answer to fix the details that are not quite there yet.  If, however, the existing answer basically missed the point of the puzzle, you might explain how the offered solution path is invalid, or offer a well placed hint to lead to the intended path, or both. In some puzzles, an unintended solution path can in fact be not only valid but an improvement on the intended solution; in others, it may just be a lucky guess. Your call here :)

Comment: You say "a movie" twice; is that your lateral thinking way of saying "two movies"???

Comment: Not really, it's a single movie

Comment: So then why did you edit the accepted answer, commenting “Improved solution in order to accept it”, to add a second movie?

Comment: Actually, I added a game, but it's not the answer: the game's name is part of the hint itself. I just linked it to explain the connection better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this movie be:

> [Stand by Me?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_by_Me_(film)). The character is standing next to word "me", which is what gave me the idea first. Also, the colossus represents [Shadow of the Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus), which here is represented by a giant being standing on its legs, which seemed to fit. If you were "Standing on the shoulders of giants", you would, in the context, stand by "me".

Comment: I thought of that but it doesn't explain the faded, slanting "colossus"?

Comment: It is, but I'd love to know how you came to that conclusion, though

Comment: @HugoBDesigner I edited my answer to explain so. Maybe that was the wrong way to find it, but that's literally what the pictures reminded me.

Comment: It is very close to the intended logic, congratulations! Not quite there yet, though, it has a couple missing links

Comment: Does it have to do with the way the word is outlined?

Comment: No, and the colors don't mean anything either

Comment: Hm.  I really don't see how the "Colossus" dropshadow contributes to this answer;  you could get to this answer with only the figure and the 'ME', right?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> [Super Size Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Size_Me)

Explanation

> Well, the picture is an enlarged person, and then there is the "ME" to complete the movie title.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's:

> [Shadow of the Colossus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1414372/)
>
>  Because the purple figure looks like a shadow and there's literally the word "colossus" in the picture. The "ME" refers to the fact that it is based off a video game, which literally puts you inside the action.

Comment: You figured part of the solution, but not the whole. Remember, the final answer is the name of a movie ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> *I am Giant* from 2015

Because:

> It is an image of a colossus with the label "me".

Comment: That wasn't the solution I had in mind, but it does fit in quite neatly with all the hints, nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on OP Hint + @Laurel answer

I guess it is:

> **Shadow of the Giant (2005)**

Because:

> As you can see, this character represents a giant as its shadow suggests: colossus.
>  And me? I'm that character, which is only a shadow (notice that the character is transparent).

Comment: Close, but not quite! "Me" is not ON the shoulders ;)

Comment: Btw, if I want to make another guess because previous one is incorrect, is it appropriate to edit previous answer like this?

Comment: Yes, you can add more text above this answer with headings old or new answer

Answer (score 0):

Might be

> [My Giant 1998](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120765/)

Explanation

> You can read it as Me Giant and it becomes My Giant (1998) movie

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Reign Over Me

?

Stolen from Laurel and adding a bit of trivia, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

> Stand by Me, based on "The Body" by King.

because

> The human figure is, literally, standing by the word "me", and is based on (as in, standing on) Colossus.
>  Colossus = King (aka Stephen King, author of "The body").

Answer (score 0):

The movie is

> [Come Wander With Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1937124/) (2011)

The rationale:

> We are shown a character standing on top of a skewed, drop-shadow of the word "Colossus", which is clearly a reference to Team Ico's video game [Shadow of the Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus).  In that game, the player character spends most of his time climbing around on top of Colossi (giant monstrous beasts), so that's presumably who the iconic figure represents.  That character is officially named *Wander*.
>
> In this rebus, we have the character Wander accompanying 'me', presumably traveling over the "colossus" text together.  Hence, "Come Wander With Me".

Comment: Though not the answer I was looking for, I find this a much more interesting solution than what I had for the puzzle, great job! You did get one of the parts of the rebus right, though!